# Export Thunder Client API Request and Response as csv (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: json, api, visual-studio-2010, thunderclient

I have imported json files in VS Code containing collections and environments to run APIs. I am using the marketplace extension "Thunder Client" to run my collections.

After running my collections/apis, how can I save the request body and response body for each independent API within a given collection? Looking to export both as a csv but a different file type will work.

inputting code in request scripts. at one point I was able to export the request body but I havent been able to export the request body yet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.